# Redirecting url using .htaccess in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a sub directory named "blog". I want to clean the url when accessing this directory in web browser. So I want that when I type

```
www.example.com/blog/index.php?id=1
```

The webbroswer must show like this:

```
www.example.com/blog/posts/1
```

I successfully implemented this when there was no sub directory, but in sub directory case it shows me a 404 error.

Here what I have done in my .htaccess file to make it work when I was implementing it in the **root** directory(not in  the subdirectory).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

And I wrote my url in the `index.php` file as

```
echo '<a href="www.example.com/posts/' . $row['id'] . '">' .  $row['title']  . '</a>';
```

But the problem is when the same thing I tried to implement in a sub directory named "blog", it shows me a 404 error.

I tried this `rule` in `.htaccess`., but it did not work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

**I am keeping my `.htaccess` file in the sub directory named `blog`.**

I tried many questions in `StackOverflow`, but none seems to solve my problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a rewwrite base to the rules that you had:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

These would be in the htaccess file in the directory `/blog/`

And make sure in your index.php, you are generating links like:

```
echo '<a href="www.example.com/blog/posts/' . $row['id'] . '">' .  $row['title']  . '</a>';
```

Comment: I have already done this, but `RewriteBase` does not seem to work, as it uses the root directory's `index.php` file. This means when i go for this link in hope that `index.php` file of `blog` will be served, it does not. Instead it serves the `index.php` file of root directory.

Comment: @AmitYadav remove the `/` before index.php.